# How to bind Label text to string property in code behind?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, data-binding

I looked at all the posts about this that I could find and none of them are answering the question in a way that I understand. I am slowly trying to build an app that keeps track of life for a card game. Right now, I am just trying to get the life total to display so I can then define my methods for the two increment and decrement buttons to do their thing. I have worked in back end stuff before so I understand how to get the buttons to do their thing but I am not understanding why my life total string is not displaying as text.

here is the xml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Notes.MainPage">
<StackLayout Margin="10,35,10,10">
    <Label 

           Text="{Binding lifeTotalString}"
           FontSize="30"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           FontAttributes="Bold"/>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Text="-"
                Clicked="btnDecrement" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                Text="+"
                Clicked="btnIncrement"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

here is the code behind

```
namespace Notes
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int lifeTotal = 20;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string lifeTotalString = lifeTotal.ToString();
    }

    void btnDecrement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void btnIncrement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind to a `BindableProperty` in code behind and set the `BindingContext` correctly:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int lifeTotal = 20;

    public static readonly BindableProperty lifeTotalStringProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(lifeTotalString),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MainPage),
            default(string));

    public string lifeTotalString
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(lifeTotalStringProperty);
        set => SetValue(lifeTotalStringProperty, value);
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lifeTotalString = lifeTotal.ToString();

        BindingContext = this;
    }

    void btnDecrement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lifeTotal--;

        lifeTotalString = lifeTotal.ToString();
    }

    void btnIncrement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lifeTotal++;

        lifeTotalString = lifeTotal.ToString();
    }
}
```

> Data bindings connect properties of two objects, called the source and
>   the target. In code, two steps are required: The BindingContext
>   property of the target object must be set to the source object, and
>   the SetBinding method (often used in conjunction with the Binding
>   class) must be called on the target object to bind a property of that
>   object to a property of the source object.
>
> The target property must be a bindable property, which means that the
>   target object must derive from BindableObject.

You can read the document for more details: [data-bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#data-bindings) and [Xamarin.Forms Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)

Comment: hey, can you also add the relevant XAML please?